# Region growing for multiple seeds in Matlab

Tags: matlab, region

Are there any functions in Matlab that enable region growing for multiple seeds?

Thanks.

Comment: Please elaborate. It is not clear (for me at least), what you're asking.

Comment: Have a look at `imreconstruct`. It may be equivalent to region growing with multiple seeds and works with all numeric format.

Comment: Multiple seeds for the same intensity value you mean?  If you want to segment just multiple regions, call the single seed code multiple times

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a slightly different approach from here:
http://www.shawnlankton.com/2008/03/growcut-segmentation-in-matlab/

Or why not take this region growing algorithm as a base: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/19084-region-growing/content/regiongrowing.m and simply add a for-loop to loop over your seeds!?

But yes, I did neither find an existing algorithm on the internet.